# How to display featured product in product view page pf prestashop

Tags: prestashop

I just want to show some featured products on each category page (not home page). how it will display?

i am using prestashop 1.5 version

Advance Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should create a module and hook it on product hooks that you want to show it.
In module you should use this code in tpl file:

```
{if isset($products) AND $products}
        <div class="block_content">
            {assign var='liHeight' value=250}
            {assign var='nbItemsPerLine' value=4}
            {assign var='nbLi' value=$products|@count}
            {math equation="nbLi/nbItemsPerLine" nbLi=$nbLi nbItemsPerLine=$nbItemsPerLine assign=nbLines}
            {math equation="nbLines*liHeight" nbLines=$nbLines|ceil liHeight=$liHeight assign=ulHeight}
            <ul style="height:{$ulHeight}px;">
            {foreach from=$products item=product name=homeFeaturedProducts}
                {math equation="(total%perLine)" total=$smarty.foreach.homeFeaturedProducts.total perLine=$nbItemsPerLine assign=totModulo}
                {if $totModulo == 0}{assign var='totModulo' value=$nbItemsPerLine}{/if}
                <li class="ajax_block_product {if $smarty.foreach.homeFeaturedProducts.first}first_item{elseif $smarty.foreach.homeFeaturedProducts.last}last_item{else}item{/if} {if $smarty.foreach.homeFeaturedProducts.iteration%$nbItemsPerLine == 0}last_item_of_line{elseif $smarty.foreach.homeFeaturedProducts.iteration%$nbItemsPerLine == 1} {/if} {if $smarty.foreach.homeFeaturedProducts.iteration > ($smarty.foreach.homeFeaturedProducts.total - $totModulo)}last_line{/if}">
                    <a href="{$product.link}" title="{$product.name|escape:html:'UTF-8'}" class="product_image"><img src="{$link->getImageLink($product.link_rewrite, $product.id_image, 'home_default')}" height="{$homeSize.height}" width="{$homeSize.width}" alt="{$product.name|escape:html:'UTF-8'}" />{if isset($product.new) && $product.new == 1}<span class="new">{l s='New' mod='homefeatured'}</span>{/if}</a>
                    <h5><a href="{$product.link}" title="{$product.name|truncate:50:'...'|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}">{$product.name|truncate:35:'...'|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}</a></h5>
                    <div class="product_desc"><a href="{$product.link}" title="{l s='More' mod='homefeatured'}">{$product.description_short|strip_tags|truncate:65:'...'}</a></div>
                    <div>
                        <a class="lnk_more" href="{$product.link}" title="{l s='View' mod='homefeatured'}">{l s='View' mod='homefeatured'}</a>
                        {if $product.show_price AND !isset($restricted_country_mode) AND !$PS_CATALOG_MODE}<p class="price_container"><span class="price">{if !$priceDisplay}{convertPrice price=$product.price}{else}{convertPrice price=$product.price_tax_exc}{/if}</span></p>{else}<div style="height:21px;"></div>{/if}

                        {if ($product.id_product_attribute == 0 OR (isset($add_prod_display) AND ($add_prod_display == 1))) AND $product.available_for_order AND !isset($restricted_country_mode) AND $product.minimal_quantity == 1 AND $product.customizable != 2 AND !$PS_CATALOG_MODE}
                            {if ($product.quantity > 0 OR $product.allow_oosp)}
                            <a class="exclusive ajax_add_to_cart_button" rel="ajax_id_product_{$product.id_product}" href="{$link->getPageLink('cart')}?qty=1&amp;id_product={$product.id_product}&amp;token={$static_token}&amp;add" title="{l s='Add to cart' mod='homefeatured'}">{l s='Add to cart' mod='homefeatured'}</a>
                            {else}
                            <span class="exclusive">{l s='Add to cart' mod='homefeatured'}</span>
                            {/if}
                        {else}
                            <div style="height:23px;"></div>
                        {/if}
                    </div>
                </li>
            {/foreach}
            </ul>
        </div>
    {else}
        <p>{l s='No featured products' mod='homefeatured'}</p>
    {/if}
```

And this code on hook function:

```
$category = new Category(Context::getContext()->shop->getCategory(), (int)Context::getContext()->language->id);
        $nb = (int)(Configuration::get('HOME_FEATURED_NBR'));
        $products = $category->getProducts((int)Context::getContext()->language->id, 1, ($nb ? $nb : 10));

        $this->smarty->assign(array(
            'products' => $products,
            'add_prod_display' => Configuration::get('PS_ATTRIBUTE_CATEGORY_DISPLAY'),
            'homeSize' => Image::getSize('home_default'),
        ));
```